# java - class attribute type change with inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass

I have a MyClass which has an attribute of type MyAttribute.
This class is inherited by MySubClass which has an attribute of type MySubAttribute.
MySubAttribute is a subclass of  MyAttribute :

```java
class MyClass {
    MyAttribute myAttribute;
    MyClass(MyAttribute myAttribute) {
        this.myAttribute = myAttribute;
    }

    MyAttribute getMyAttribute() {
        return myAttribute;
    }
}

class MySubClass extends MyClass {
    MySubClass(MySubAttribute mySubAttribute) {
        super(mySubAttribute);
    }
}


class MyAttribute {
    void doSomething() {
    }
}

class MySubAttribute extends MyAttribute {
    @Override
    void doSomething() {
        super.doSomething();
    }
    void doSomethingElse() {
    }
}
```

Now imagine that I have the following code:

```
mySubClass.getMyAttribute();
```

How to make the returned value of type MySubAttribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [Java Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Also, you no longer need to define MySubClass unless you wanna add extra methods or properties to it.

```java
class MyClass<T extends MyAttribute> {
  T myAttribute;
  MyClass(T myAttribute) {
    this.myAttribute = myAttribute;
  }

  T getMyAttribute() {
    return myAttribute;
  }
}


class MyAttribute {
  void doSomething() {
    System.out.println("Doing something...");
  }
}

class MySubAttribute extends MyAttribute {
  void doSomethingElse() {
    System.out.println("Doing something else...");
  }
}

// You would instantiate `mySubClass` as follows
MyClass<MySubAttribute> mySubClass = new MyClass<>(new MySubAttribute());
mySubClass.getMyAttribute().doSomethingElse();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add something like this to `MySubClass`:

```
@Override
MySubAttribute getMyAttribute() {
    return new MySubAttribute();
}
```

Comment: I assume you are asking about the static return type.  The way the code is written in your question, `mySubClass.getMyAttribute()` is already going to return a `MySubAttribute` instance, assuming `mySubClass` points to an instance of `MySubClass`.

Comment: I don't think so because when i do : mySubCass.getMyAttribute(); the method who is used is that whic is in MyClass. So the retuned value type is MyAttribute.

Comment: "the method who is used is that whic is in MyClass. So the retuned value type is MyAttribute" - That static return type is `MyAttribute` but the type of the object returned is `MySubAttribute`.

Comment: So how to do this: `MySubAttribute msa = mySubClass.getAttribute();` `msa.doSomethingElse();`    because it doesn't compile and I would like to avoid using casting @JeffScottBrown

Comment: `MySubAttribute msa = (MySubAttribute)mySubClass.getAttribute(); msa.doSomethingElse();`

Comment: "it doesn't compile and I would like to avoid using casting" - that is an odd requirement, but overriding the method as described in the answer will allow that.

Comment: Emerick, either [A] what you say just isn't how java works, so double check your code and exactly what you are compiling: If `MySubClass` overrides `getMyAttribute` such that its return type is defined as `MySubAttribute`, the type of the expression `mySubClassInstance.getAttribute()` certainly is `MySubAttribute`, or [B] the type of the `mySubClass` variable is `MyClass`, in which case, no, of course, what you want is completely impossible, think about it.

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution is generics:

```
class MyClass<A extends MyAttribute> {
    A myAttribute;
    MyClass(A myAttribute) {
        this.myAttribute = myAttribute;
    }

    A getMyAttribute() {
        return myAttribute;
    }
}

class MySubClass extends MyClass<MySubAttribute> {
```

Alternatively, you could have MySubClass override the getter with a narrower return type:

```
    @Override
    MySubAttribute getMyAttribute() {
        // we know the cast succeeds because we have set a MySubAttribute in the constructor
        return (MySubAttribute) myAttribute; 
    }
```

The generic solution offers better compile time checking of the implementing class, and allows a caller to refer to the type of the attribute even if they don't know the subtype of `MyClass` by writing `MyClass<MySubAttribute>`. On the other hand, the generic solution does require callers to write a type parameter (even if just `MyClass<?>`), so calling code gets slightly more verbose.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, then you're asking for:

```
public interface HasMyAttribute {
    MyAttribute getMyAttribute();
}

public class MyClass implements HasMyAttribute {
    private MyAttribute myAttribute;

    public MyClass(MyAttribute myAttribute) {
        this.myAttribute = myAttribute;
    }

    @Override
    public MyAttribute getMyAttribute() {
        return this.myAttribute;
    }
}

public class MySubClass extends MyClass implements HasMyAttribute {

    private MySubAttribute mySubAttribute;

    public MySubClass(MySubAttribute mySubAttribute) {
        super(mySubAttribute);
        this.mySubAttribute = mySubAttribute;
    }

    @Override
    public MySubAttribute getMyAttribute() {
        return mySubAttribute;
    }
}
```

(though, if you don't need two distinct concrete classes, @xxMrPHDxx's answer is much better)

Comment: If you do this there will be 2 attribute references in every instance of `MySubClass`, those will be `mySubAttribute` and `myAttribute`, and both references will point to the same instance.  This is almost certainly not desireable.

Comment: Ok, I'll bite. Why?

Comment: "Ok, I'll bite. Why?" - `myAttribute` is defined in `MyClass` so there will be a private `myAttribute` field and because of the getter there will be a public `myAttribute` property (as distinct from the field).  `MySubClass` extends `MyClass` so it inherits those things, and then in addition to that is a `mySubAttribute` field and property defined in `MySubClass`.

Comment: I wasn't asking why there would be 2 references in every instance of `MySubClass`, I was asking why it was not desirable. Is there some sort of reference limit to a single instance we're supposed to maintain, or some other obscure design principle I'm not aware of?

Comment: "Is there some sort of reference limit to a single instance we're supposed to maintain, or some other obscure design principle I'm not aware of?" - No.  There isn't any sort of reference limit in the JVM (not one that you have any practical reason to care about), and I wouldn't consider the design principles in question to be obscure at all.